# Django-messages works only when form|crispy is used but not in other cases

Tags: python, django, django-messages

I am creating a login page using django but it does not show any messages when I enter wrong passwords or email addresses. I've also checked other messages but it didn't help.

login.html

```
    <div class="right">
        <h2>Login</h2>

        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                  {{ message }}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="label">Email or Username</div>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="label">Password</div>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button class="login" type="submit">LOGIN</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div class="sign_up">
            <small>Don’t have an account yet?</small>
            <a class="signup" href="{% url 'register' %}">SIGN UP</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

urls.py has this path for the login page(I have imported all the necessary classes):

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html') , name='login'),
```

But the messages are shown when I use this `form|crispy` in login.html

```
        <div class="content-section">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Login</legend>
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign In</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="border-top pt-3">
                <small class="muted-text">
                    Want a new Account? <a class="ml-1" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a>
                </small>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you used **LoginView** using form it will return it will show you **error** because of `{{ form|crispy }}` template tag render **form** and **fields** along with **field.errors** and **field.non_field_error**.

That's Why you can get an error message if you remove **message** block in your code it will show you an error there is no connection with form and message in login view

If you want to render you HTML form with CSS you need to explicitly define **errors** showing block like this

```
 <div class="right">
        <h2>Login</h2>

       {% if form.errors %}

        {% for field in form %}
           {% for error in field.errors %}
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
              </div>
           {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

           {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                 <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
              </div>
           {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="label">Email or Username</div>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="label">Password</div>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button class="login" type="submit">LOGIN</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div class="sign_up">
            <small>Don’t have an account yet?</small>
            <a class="signup" href="{% url 'register' %}">SIGN UP</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here not meaning to use the message framework of Django. Form it self return error in his errors attribute of a form
Hope you satisfied with this answer